# Calculate running count of events for continuous dates in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, grouping

I have data that can be summarized as follows:

```
eventid startdate   enddate     productkey  date        startGroup  endGroup    eventGroup
123     2020-01-01  2020-01-10  123456      2020-01-01  1           0           1
123     2020-01-01  2020-01-10  123456      2020-01-02  0           0           1
123     2020-01-01  2020-01-10  123456      2020-01-03  0           0           1
123     2020-01-01  2020-01-10  123456      2020-01-04  0           1           1
234     2020-01-05  2020-01-07  123456      2020-01-05  1           0           2
234     2020-01-05  2020-01-07  123456      2020-01-06  0           0           2
234     2020-01-05  2020-01-07  123456      2020-01-07  0           1           2
123     2020-01-01  2020-01-10  123456      2020-01-08  1           0           1
123     2020-01-01  2020-01-10  123456      2020-01-09  0           0           1
123     2020-01-01  2020-01-10  123456      2020-01-10  0           1           1
```

I store various events for products. Since they can be overlapping, I already have code to de-dup the data, but now, with some of the (de-duped) days missing, I need to put the data back together at an event level. In the example data, you see two events, 123 (running from 1/1 to 1/10) and 234 (running from 1/5 to 1/7). I already cut out the middle two days to get rid of overlaps and what I want output-wise, is three groups of events

- 1/1-1/4 (i.e. last column = 1)
- 1/5-1/7 (i.e. last column = 2)
- 1/8-1/10 (i.e. last column = 3)

I already have code to find the right start and end entries for each block of time, but don't know how to calculate the eventGroup column correctly. Current code for the last three columns is as follows:

```sql
CASE WHEN DATEADD(DAY, -1, date) = LAG(date) OVER (PARTITION BY eventid, productkey ORDER BY date) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END startGroup,
CASE WHEN DATEADD(DAY, +1, date) = LEAD(date) OVER (PARTITION BY eventid, productkey ORDER BY date) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END endGroup,
dense_rank() over (order by eventid, productkey) eventGroup
```

I already tried things like https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/193680/group-rows-by-uninterrupted-dates, but still wasn't able to create the correct groups.

In Excel logic, it would be eventGroup = if ( startGroup = 0, eventGroup of previous row, eventGroup of previous row + 1), but not sure how to replicate that running counter here.

Can someone help please? Thanks!

Comment: You need to show, as tabular text, both your sample data and your expected results. Also if you provide your sample data as DDL+DML you make it much easier for us to copy and paste out to assist.

Answer (score 2):

To assign the groups, use a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*,
       sum(startGroup) over (partition by eventId, productKey order by startdate)
from t;
```

Note:  This assumes that you want to restart the numbering with event/product combination.